# <div> que funciona como se fosse uma <textarea> não quebra linha quando é enviado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Estou com um plugin de comentários para `WordPress` que está com um pequeno problema.

Ele funciona assim:

É uma `<div>` que funciona como se fosse uma `<textarea>`, só que por funcionar assim, quando a pessoa quer digita um comentário e ela dá um `"enter"` para quebrar a linha e depois enviar o comentário, o comentário chega sem quebra de linha, ele chega como se a pessoa não tivesse dado uma quebra.

Como fica o código HTML:

```
<div class="commentator-textarea" placeholder="Junte-se" contenteditable=""></div>
```

**[Javascript no Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n3tuKvn8)**

***Imagens:***

**Exemplo de comentário:**
[image]
**Como fica depois de comentado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma solução para isso?

Se eu comentar e quebrar a linha usando `Vou quebrar a<br>linha` ele funciona.

Depois de comentado fica:

Vou quebrar a

linha

Comment: Pelo que eu vi, o atributo `contenteditable` utiliza tags `<br>` paras quebra de linha, então teóricamente deveria funcionar. Você tem que ver como o código do comentário está chegando no PHP. As vezes o JavaScript pode estar tirando as tags geradas automaticamente e por isto está dando errado.

Comment: @Kazzkiq
Só que eu não quero que para as pessoas quebrarem a linha necessite que eles coloquem `<br>` no comentário.
Quero que do jeito que a pessoa comentar o mesmo chegue igual.

Comment: Sempre que voce submeter o texto para o servidor substitua o '<br/>' por '\n'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando a função [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) do jQuery para enviar o comentário. Esta função, ao contrário da [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), pega somente o **texto** do elemento que você definiu, e exclui quaisquer tags HTML que estejam junto.

Trocando:

```
$form.find('.commentator-textarea').text()
```

por:

```
$form.find('.commentator-textarea').html()
```

Deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Em qual linha está isso? Onde você encontrou ?

Comment: Na linha **11** do seu pastebin.

Comment: Sim! Vou testar agora :D

Comment: Êbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!!! Funciounou, você é o cara! Vlw muito obrigado! loooooooooool Vlw cara! rsrs

Comment: Fico feliz que te ajudei. O lado bom de quebrar a cabeça com um problema por muito tempo é que você consegue identificá-lo de imediato em outras ocasiões (acredite, eu sofri muito com esse `.text()`). Uma boa dica é sempre averiguar se a função utilizada tem algum *porém* ou alguma limitação para evitar esse tipo de errinho chato. :)

Comment: Muitooo Legal! Muito obrigado! Genial :P

Answer (score 1):

Não trabalho com PHP e muito menos com wordpress, minha área é ASP.NET e C#, mas no seu caso acho que vou saber lhe dar a solução.

Em qualquer campo texto em html (imput, textarea) quando recebe é enviado o texto ao servidor as quebras de linhas são tradas com caráteres especiais no caso da quebra de linha é um `\n` (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_linha). No banco de dados dever estar armazenando assim.

Solução, você deve tratar a entrega (apresentação do texto) simplesmente dando um replace de `\n` para `<br/>`.

Função em PHP pra fazer o replace:

```
$resultado = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $variavel_com_o_texto);
```

Comment: Isso funcionaria se o campo fosse um textarea comum, mas é um div com `contenteditable`.